# How do you implement the inverse of bit shift operations in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, reverse-engineering

When reverse engineering C code that uses bit shift operations, I'm confused on the methodology behind getting the inverse the code below.

```
unsigned char red = 37;
unsigned char blue = 100;
unsigned char green = 77
unsigned short us = (red << 8) + (blue);
us = (us << 5 ) | (us >> 11);
unsigned int threebytes = (us << 8) + green;
```

Since NOT is the operation for inverting bits, I assumed I could implement a NOT to invert the bits at each line or at the end of the code, however, my result doesn't match up with the expected output which leads me to believe that I've come to a misunderstanding. What am I not understanding about reverse engineering?

Comment: That's not called "reverse engineering", and there's no `NOT` operation here. If you don't know what the operators are, you need to read a C book first instead

Comment: I'm not following here. If you bitshift left, then you can invert the operation with a bitshift to the right and vice versa.

Comment: You have not explained what your expected output is. Please do that, and use binary for both input and output.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a class exercise in understanding C bit operations. It further appears to assume that `unsigned char` is eight bits and `unsigned short` is 16 bits, and likely that `unsigned int` is 32 bits. Your job for the exercise is to understand which bits are moved where and to design new operations that will move the bits from the resulting value in `threebytes` back to their original values in three separate variables.

Here is some help in understanding the code:

```
unsigned short us = (red << 8) + (blue);
```

This code shifts the value of `red` left (higher) eight bits and puts the value of `blue` in the low eight bits.

```
us = (us << 5 ) | (us >> 11);
```

This performs what is effectively a rotation of bits. Suppose we label the 16 bits in `us` so that we can track them:

```
fedcba9876543210
```

The expression `us << 5` produces this in 16 bits (the intermediate result actually has 32 due to C rules, but the high 16 will be discarded later, so we ignore them):

```
a9876543210_____
```

The underscores represent new 0 bits that are shifted in. The other digits are labels for the previous bit values.

The expression `us >> 11` produces this:

```
___________fedcb.
```

When these are combined with `|` in `(us << 5) |`(us >> 11)`, the result is:

```
a9876543210fedcb
```

Thus, the original bits `fedcba9876543210` have been rotated to be `a9876543210fedcb`.

Then this:

```
unsigned int threebytes = (us << 8) + green
```

shifts the 16 bits from `us` left eight bits and inserts the value of `green` in the low eight bits.

From this, you should be able to understand where all the bits in `red`, `blue`, and `green` end up in `threebytes`. Then exercise is then for you to write new code that will move those bits from `threebytes` back to separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean inverting in the sense of decoding `threebytes` back to its constituent RGB components.

First let's just look at what `threebytes` even looks like.

The first step `(red << 8) + (blue)` makes a 16 bit number formatted like `rrrr rrrr bbbb bbbb`.

The second step, `(us << 5 ) | (us >> 11)`, is a rotate-left by 5 bits, so the result looks like `rrrb bbbb bbbr rrrr` (where the `r` bits at the bottom are actually the *top* 5 bits of the red channel).

The last step `(us << 8) + green` appends the green bits to it, making `rrrb bbbb bbbr rrrr gggg gggg`.

The steps can be un-done by (as usual) taking the opposite steps and performing them in reverse order (this principle is familiar from "put on socks, then put on shoes" which is undone by "take off shoes, then take of socks"). So:

```
// rrrb bbbb bbbr rrrr gggg gggg
// take green from the bottom 8 bits
unsigned char green = threebytes;

// take the remaining mixed R and B bits
unsigned short us = threebytes >> 8;
// rrrb bbbb bbbr rrrr
// rotate right by 5
us = (us << 11) | (us >> 5);
// rrrr rrrr bbbb bbbb
// split into red and blue
unsigned char blue = us;
unsigned char red = us >> 8;
```